# Can't use all of .pt files to train. it's broken

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, yolo

I'm not good at English, sorry.

I'm working to make detect object in realtime program.
So I trained by YOLOv8, and made a best.pt and last.pt files.

But I think I have a mistake about encoding type at the different time.
I know about this trouble when I execute my already created detecting object program by webcam.
And now I want broken .pt files to make useful. what should I do?

It's not perfect code now.
If you need more information, I'll provide.

---

```
pip install ultralytics
from ultralytics import YOLO
from ultralytics.yolo.utils.ops import scale_image
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)

classNames = ["Hole"]

def predict_on_image(model, img, conf):
    result = model(img, conf=conf)[0]

   
    cls = result.boxes.cls.cpu().numpy()   
    probs = result.boxes.conf.cpu().numpy() 
    boxes = result.boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy()  

  
    masks = result.masks.data.cpu().numpy()    
    masks = np.moveaxis(masks, 0, -1) )
    
   
    masks = scale_image(masks, img.shape)
    masks = np.moveaxis(masks, -1, 0) 

    return boxes, masks, cls, probs

def overlay(image, mask, color, alpha, resize=None):
    
    # color = color[::-1]
    colored_mask = np.expand_dims(mask, 0).repeat(3, axis=0)
    colored_mask = np.moveaxis(colored_mask, 0, -1)
    masked = np.ma.MaskedArray(image, mask=colored_mask, fill_value=color)
    image_overlay = masked.filled()

    if resize is not None:
        image = cv2.resize(image.transpose(1, 2, 0), resize)
        image_overlay = cv2.resize(image_overlay.transpose(1, 2, 0), resize)

    image_combined = cv2.addWeighted(image, 1 - alpha, image_overlay, alpha, 0)

    return image_combined

model = YOLO('best.pt')

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    results = model(img, stream=True)
   
    #boxes, masks, cls, probs = predict_on_image(model, img, conf=0.2)
    

    image_with_masks = np.copy(img)
   
    for r in results:
        boxes = r.boxes

        for box in boxes:
           
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0]
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2) # 정수 값으로 변환
            

            cv2.rectangle(image_with_masks, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 0), 1)
            
            confidence = math.ceil((box.conf[0]*100))/100 #점수, 0~1 사이로 표현
            print("신뢰도 =>", confidence)

            cls = int(box.cls[0])
            print("클래스 이름 ==>", classNames[cls])
            print("신뢰도 =>", confidence)

            org = [x1, y1]
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            fontScale = 1
            color = (0, 0, 255) 
            thickness = 2

            cv2.putText(image_with_masks, classNames[cls], org, font, fontScale, color, thickness)
            
    cv2.imshow('웹캠', image_with_masks)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()ere
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umKtz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSiyN.png)

I tried delete and reinstall visual studio code, and used chatGPT but I can't solve it.
please help me.

Comment: It is not useful to open .pt file in a text editor) Why do you think your model files are actually broken? Do you get any errors during executing this code?